# Is there any way to start an EC2 instance from an Azure DevOps release pipeline?

Tags: amazon-ec2, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-devops-extensions

The instance is already created but i dont want to run it manually on AWS everytime i need it.

Also, we have some problems executing code based pipelines so if there is any way to do it graphically it would be awesome.

THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

The [AWS Toolkit for Azure DevOps](https://aws.amazon.com/vsts/) is an extension for hosted and on-premises Microsoft Azure DevOps that make it easy to manage and deploy applications using AWS.

This [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AmazonWebServices.aws-vsts-tools&utm_source=roundupblog) adds tasks to easily enable build and release pipelines in Azure DevOps and Azure DevOps Server to work with AWS services including Amazon S3, AWS Elastic Beanstalk, AWS CodeDeploy, AWS Lambda, AWS CloudFormation, Amazon Simple Queue Service and Amazon Simple Notification Service, and run commands using the AWS Tools for Windows PowerShell module and the AWS CLI.

Thus you could use AWS CLI task to [launch your EC2 instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-services-ec2-instances.html).

Comment: Hi Victor, Does my answer work? Please check it and kindly let me know the result.

Comment: Hi Edward...we opted for another implementation so we didn't check your proposed solution. Sorry for the late answer.